# Tweepy "No Access_token Data Was Acquired"

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

Having trouble getting the oauth access token and secret exchanged from the request tokens any help would be great everything else seems to be in the right place

```
 TweepError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized


callback_url = urllib.quote("%s?twitterCallback=1" % self.request.url)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)#, callback_url

try:
    redirect_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print 'Error! Failed to get request token.'

request_token = [auth.request_token.key, auth.request_token.secret]

tmpldict['twitauthurl'] = redirect_url

oauth_verifier = self.request.values.get('oauth_verifier',None)
oauth_token = self.request.values.get('oauth_token',None)

if oauth_verifier:
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

    auth.set_request_token(request_token[0], request_token[1])

    access_token = {}
    try:
            access_token = auth.get_access_token(oauth_verifier)

    except tweepy.TweepError:
            print 'Error! Failed to get access token.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to store the request token data in the session and recall it in the second part. the call was creating a new request token.